# Able to Get Value in Console, But Undefined When Called From Function in Angular 2 App

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, object

I am running into an issue in my Angular 2 app where I'm getting an `undefined` error that's not making sense to me. What's more perplexing is that, after getting the `undefined` error, I can effectively check the exact same value in the console and get it with no issues.

First off, here's a version of the function that DOES work:

```
public getApplicableResult()
{
    if (!this.customer || !this.customer.services || !this.customer.services.getAt(0))
    {
        console.log('Services not available...');
        return;
    }
    else if (this.customer && this.customer.services && this.customer.services.getAt(0))
    {
        console.log(this.customer.services.getAt(0));
    }
```

When I run this function I get this in the console for my "console.dir" of my object literal:

```
CustomerServiceDetails
  assignments:(...)
  authorizations:(...)
```

If I then click on "assignments" in the console, I get this expanded result:

```
assignments:
  CustomerAssignmentCollection
  count:1
  items:Array(1)
```

So all the data is seemingly there and available.

However, if, in my function, if I were to try and access these nested values more directly - such as the value for "count" above, I get an `undefined` error. That's what I'm not understanding. Perhaps it's something I misunderstand about how the console works. But if seems to me that if I can access the value for this property in the console, then I should be able to access it directly via my function.

Here's an example of the same function, slightly altered to get the result for "count" within assignments, that returns `undefined`:

```
public getApplicableResult()
{
    if (!this.customer || !this.customer.services || !this.customer.services.getAt(0).assignments)
    {
        console.log('Services not available...');
        return;
    }
    else if (this.customer && this.customer.services && this.customer.services.getAt(0).assignments)
    {
        console.dir(this.customer.services.getAt(0).assignments.count);
    }
```

The specific error I get is:

```
Cannot read property 'assignments' of undefined;
```

To add some additional info, `assignments` is not an array, it's a collection.

Two questions here:

1.) Why isn't my first "if" clause handling the 'undefined' error? How could I adjust it to handle the situation better?

2.) Why can I call the first function, get a result, and then drill down from there in the console to get what I need,  but if I try and access a more nested part of the object in the function itself, I get `undefined` as a result?

One additional detail, I was calling this via Angular's `ngAfterViewChecked()`. So what that should do, even if it's a timing issue, is return the first "if" else clause result until the value is available, and then it should show the result - i.e., it should execute the "else if" block - because AfterViewChecked() keeps checking. But this isn't happening. I'm just getting the `undefined` result I mentioned above.

Comment: Can you include the component and "services" variable declaration?
I think your problem is using getAt function, because services doesnt have "getAt" function or cannot convert it to js.
Try "this.customer.services[0].assignments.count"

Comment: Tried your suggestion. Still returned the same 'undefined' error.

Comment: 1) Because it is `this.customer.services.getAt(0)` that is undefined, and you try to access property without checking first if it is defined or not. 2) Because you do that at different moments of time. Obviously, the object becomes available at some point. It's impossible to say anything more specific because the question needs http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , otherwise it is considered off-topic.

Comment: @estus, did you read the first part of my question?
 I made it clear that this.customer.services.getAt(0) does NOT return 'undefined'. It is this.customer.services.getAt(0).assignments that returns 'undefined'. That's where my confusion lies.

Comment: If it weren't, you wouldn't see this error. `Cannot read property 'assignments' of undefined` means that it is getAt(0) that is undefined. The question cannot be answered in its current state because it doesn't contain enough data to make conclusions.

Comment: If what you're saying is true, then the first function above would return "undefined". It doesn't. Isn't it clear that that's where my confusion lies? What you're saying would seem to follow. And yet, as I clearly state above, when I use the first function I get a result in the console -- the results of which I spell out in detail.

Comment: It is true because this is exactly what this JS error means. The fact that you've checked it doesn't mean that you did this correctly, otherwise you wouldn't ask this question. I already explained why you can get different results in console. Please, give the readers all necessary details to replicate the problem and let them decide themselves if you were right on your assumptions or not, that's what SO rules require.

Comment: Let me say it one more time: this.customer.services.getAt(0) DOES NOT RETURN 'UNDEFINED'. Running it within ngAfterViewChecked(), it first is 'undefined', which my first 'if' clause handles, and then it resolves to the result I describe above - and so the second clause fires and I get the result in the console. And so I never get an error. Are you taking this fact into consideration?